# How to get job stats with Shoryuken?

Tags: rubygems, shoryuken

Is there a way to get job stats from Shoryuken similar stats from Sidekiq via an API (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I should be using AWS SDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/sqs-example-show-queues.html) to get such stats like number of inflight messages in the queue etc.